# Where is the Openjdk documentation located in the local install that I can point IntelliJ to? This is not to be confused with referencing a URL

Tags: java, api, intellij-idea, javadoc

I'm not familar with OpenJDK or it's files.
The issue I'm having is that I am not able to find the location for the JavaDocs. Maybe the SA did not include it within my system but within IntelliJ I'm trying to get the documentation to show up so when I click on a method I can see some information on what all is taken in as a parameter and what is returned and information about what causes exceptions.

Can someone tell me where the heck I need to point my project settings in order for it to locate the documentation for OpenJdk?
I'm referring to the local install of OpenJdk and not an external http:// path because my system I work on is NOT online.

What is the normal location where OpenJdk has its javadocs?

Comment: Please review again. This is not the same issue. I'm trying to find the documentation location for where OpenJdk keeps is javadocs.

Comment: Is the documentation even included in the OpenJDK install? I don't believe it is by default. In any case, the instructions in the duplicate will work just as well for referencing the local documentation. Just use the + icon instead of the external URL button.

Comment: The documentation never shipped with the JDK, not with OpenJDK, not with Oracle’s JDK, not when it was Sun’s JDK. When you want a local copy, you have to download it separately. Or generate it from the source code.